# Clone & Hotswap IDE harddrive advice

Tags: hard-drive, clone, dd

I am in a situation where an old tower running Windows XP will need to eventually have the hard drive replaced as it is showing signs of failure.

My plan is to clone the IDE hard disk using Linux or OS X `dd` utility.  I have a few questions about this because I am not too familiar with the IDE bus and I am seeking advice about going about this clone procedure so when the new drive is installed, there will be no detours.

MY PLAN OF ACTION:

1. remove the drive from the machine and connect it to a newer machine (Linux or Mac) and use `dd` to create an image.
2. disconnect the drive and connect the new one.
3. writing the created image to the drive using `dd`

QUESTIONS:

1. If the newer drive is of a larger size, is there a (safe) utility to expand the NTFS filesystem to cover the rest of the space without causing mayhem, or is it easier to just leave it alone?
2. Will the new drive be plug-n-play in terms of Windows booting up again, exactly before the replacement?

Comment: Although `dd` probably is suitable to create a copy/clone of a drive you really shouldn't expend any effort in keeping Windows XP alive...

Comment: diskmgmt.msc and Yes. And for the love of all that is good in the world, don't do this. Take it out back and shoot it.

Comment: I would advise using partimage rather than dd for creating and restoring a drive image.